# MySQL UPDATE statement using a table created on the fly

Tags: mysql, update, syntax

I want to update a table, say `Table 1` using a table that I create on the fly (say`temp`). To achieve this I have the following query:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET COUNT = temp.ctemp FROM ( SELECT A, SUM(UNO) AS ctemp FROM Table1
                                            GROUP BY A 
                                            ORDER BY A) 
                                      AS temp,Table1 t1
                                      WHERE temp.A = t1.A;
```

It works well in `SQL Server 2008` but `MySQL`  throws out the error

```
syntax error, unexpected FROM, expecting 'END_OF_INPUT' or ';'
```

Any idea what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`UPDATE` syntax in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html) is different than SQL-Server. This will do:

```
UPDATE Table1 AS t
  JOIN
      ( SELECT A, SUM(UNO) AS ctemp 
        FROM Table1
        GROUP BY A                     -- no need for `ORDER BY` in either DBMS
      ) AS temp
    ON temp.A = t.A  
SET 
    t.COUNT = temp.ctemp ;
```

Comment: The query worked. I had the `ORDER BY` in there to verify just the query - you were right to note that it was not needed.